# ld: library not found for -lPayPalMobile ios

Tags: ios, paypal, xcode6

i am working with xcode 6.1 on paypal integration.

i am getting following error each time when i open the project.

> ld: library not found for -lPayPalMobile
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

every time i have to remove library search paths value and remove reference of paypal folder and again import it to project.

what is the problem i don't know please tell me what to do?

**Edited**

one thing more that if project name is **"This is test"** then what will be difference?
because i can see in  **library search paths** that in first row **"This"** is coming in second row only **"is"** is there and in last (i.e. 3rd row) **"test"** is there.

Thank you.

Comment: Change your project Name folder tom "Thisistest". Then try it. No need to change project name Just change Folder name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow Below steps,

(1) Add Static library in Your project bundle.

(2) Add it in "link binary with libraries"

You need to go to your Target -> Build phase -> link binary with libraries.
as attached in below image.[image]

(3) Give proper header search path for your linked library.
    i.e. ($PROJECT_DIR)/Your path.

You can also read the steps that given in [GitHub link of PayPal,](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/)
which give you proper direction.

Feel free to ask if you need more help regarding this.

Comment: i did it though the problem is still there.

Comment: Try to remove and then add your library. be curious about Library header search path in build setting. give it exact.

Comment: please do see edited question for more detail. thank you

Comment: i did solve it by .... 
Change your project Name folder tom "Thisistest". Then try it. No need to change project name Just change Folder name.  as per Sharma Vishal said

Comment: @PremalKhetani, great. If it's helpful to you then you can up vote my answer thus other can refer it.

Answer (score 1):

As **@Anuj** mentioned this can be a problem related with **Library Search Paths**. **Cocoa Pods** sometimes gets a mess when updating it, or installing it again if you have it or not under Source Control.

I solved this problem right now by adding this flag under **Library Search Paths**:

```
$(inherited)
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: @ EridB thanks for your reply but i already solved it. and sorry for not accepting this ans as ANS coz already i accepted him ans.

Comment: @PremalKhetani it's ok! Don't worry, I answered here to help other people who are facing the same trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually Header or Library Search Paths. It's better to use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) to manage your project dependancies. CocoaPods is the dependency manager for Objective-C projects. It has thousands of libraries and can help you scale your projects elegantly. You can import any static library using simple [Podfile](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html) and command line.

Once you start using CocoaPods, you won't have to worry about header or library search paths. PayPal also has a spec in the CocoaPods Spec repository.

Comment: thanks Anuj for quick reply 
how can i create pod files and how use them?
and this error comes just for 3 days before 3 days it was working very fine.

Comment: Check the links I've provided in the answer, you can follow it easily

Comment: You should add your static library in your project. Go to Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries. Add the libPayPalMobile.a file there

Comment: i did it though the problem is still there.

Comment: Follow these steps https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/#if-you-dont-use-cocoapods-then

Comment: please do see edited question for more detail. thank you